# How to view tag manager events in analytics outside of realtime events

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a site set up with analytics and tag manager and followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUKB-1Ay5lY) on how to set up a tag that tracks button clicks. So far I've successfully created a tag that tracks clicks for a buy now button, and in google analytics I can see this in reporting -> real-time -> events, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

The problem is I can't seem to view the stats for this event outside of real-time data, which isn't helpful to me because of the 30 minute time window. I want to be able to track this event the same way analytics tracks page views. I've looked carefully through every menu option in the reporting tab and couldn't find the event, and the documentation for analytics and tag manager aren't the most helpful.

Do I have this set up properly? I'm considering abandoning the use of tag manager altogether and just writing some javascript ga() calls for the buy now click tracking as described [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events).

Comment: This is off topic as it is not related to coding, but to comment, data won't show up in your standard reports for about 24 hours as it needs to be processed. You should be looking under the Behavior Events reports.